# Nash equilibrium in p-beauty contest game where p=1

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium, behavioral-economics

Setup: players must chose a number between 0 and 100. The winner of the game is the player whose chosen number is closest to the average of all chosen numbers multiplied by "p". Assume that in a tie the reward is split equally among winners. I know that if p<1 then the Nash equilibrium is 0. If p>1 the Nash equilibrium is 100.

What about if p=1?

Is the Nash equilibrium a mixed strategy that assigns equal probability to all numbers between 0 and 100?

OR

Is the Nash equilibrium simply choosing 50 (the mean of all numbers between 0 and 100)?

OR is the Nash equilibrium something else entirely?

I am confused and so is my professor, please help :)

Comment: Is it possible there is not *a* Nash equilibrium but *several* Nash equilibria?

Comment: An example: If there are 10 players, each of them saying 79 is a Nash equilibrium, any single deviatior would lose out on the reward.

Comment: This game is only really funny if played by 2 players.